# table not resizing to input

Tags: html, css, html-input

Why does the table cell not resize to a smaller input field?

I have the following html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <td>
            <input></input>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have the following css:

```
input {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}

td {
    border: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

However the border shows that the parent(in this case the *td* element) takes the original size of the *input* element after the width is set in the css. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryangates/7WEKT/3/) of this demonstrated.

Comment: So... you want and item of width 50% to be... 100% width of the parent container? If the TD resized, the input would no longer have a width of 50%. Looks to be working as expected.

Comment: Wait what? Because you have 50% width it takes the default and half's it. So the `td` has to leave the 50% space for the input. Simple as that really.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I think I misunderstood how setting width with percent work, but I would like the input to be 50% as large as it would be normally.

Comment: @RyanGates [it's relative to the container](http://jsfiddle.net/7WEKT/4/)

Comment: @RyanGates So you want `150%`. `100%` is the `orignal + 50% (half of it again)`.

Comment: I think what he expected was that the `<td>` did wrap around its content, so to the width of the input element. Something strange is happening here imo. As it normally should act like that.

Comment: @nkmol It is kind of interesting, because there isn't really a default width for the td. It takes the full default width of the default input, then resizes the input to half that. I am going to take Deepak Mishra's advice and apply width on the table elements.

Comment: @RyanGates Indeed. There isn't any parent width. The closest parent width would be the body itself. But it also does not take the width of the body. It's odd, but interesting ^^

Comment: @RyanGates no there isn't a default width for a `td`, but there is for `input` (default size is 20)... This case is interesting... it appears the TD width is 100% for the default input size, [as shown in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WEKT/6/)... this wouldn't work for a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the fiddle and this is what i found.

```
input {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

This makes the `input` 50% wide as compared to `td`, since `td` is `input`s parent element.

Remove the 50% width and max-width from input and try applying width on table elements

Here's the formatted html.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
           <input>
          </td>
       </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So using the percentages for width will prevent the parent from resizing according to its content?

Comment: @RyanGates He means that if you're providing width to 50% of input inside that `td` then it will be the half of container means half of the `td` _100 % 2 = 50%_